# Resharper refactoring pattern to wrap a local variable assignment in try catch

Tags: c#, try-catch, resharper

If I have the following code

```
var x = foo();
DoSomethingWith(x);
```

where

```
Foo foo(){...}
```

sometimes I want to wrap this in an exception handler like so

```
Foo x;
try{
    x = foo();
}catch(Exception e){
    $InsertPoint$
}
DoSomethingWith(x);
```

Now I know how to do around templates and I've seen some information on how to do structural pattern matching. Would it be possible in R# to construct a pattern that will get the type of x ( it is declared as var ) and then generate the wrapped form with the explicit declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching `$type$ $id$ = $expr$;` and replace with

```
$type$ $id$;
try{
    $id$ = $expr$;
}catch(Exception e){
   //Insert code here
}
```

using structured search and replace. It is important to mark `$expr$` as an `expression` not as an `identifier`

Comment: That is very impressive :) I added show as hint and now I can automatically wrap my assignment in temporary try catch without buggering the flow of my code.

Comment: I'm pleased and surprised that it worked. I did it by memory.